# How to prove the following inequality between $u$ and integral of its gradient

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading a paper and it states that the following result is well known.
I can't prove it myself but would like to see a proof before I continue the reading, can anybody help?

> $\text{Let}\ u\in C_0^{\infty}(B_R(x))\ \text{where}\ B_R(x)\ \text{is a ball of radius}\ R\ \text{centered at}\ x\ \text{then}$
> $$|u(x)| \leq c \int_{B_{R}(x)} \frac{|\nabla u(y)|}{|x-y|^{n-1}} d y$$

Comment: Which paper are you reading?

Comment: @user1046533 The Local Regularity of Solutions of Degenerate Elliptic Equations by Fabes Kenig Serapioni it's a pretty old paper, I'm reading a part of it for a seminary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- Consider what is given by the divergence theorem, about the integral $\iiint \nabla f$ performed over a ball centered at $x$ with radius $r\leq R$
- Consider how the surface area of the previous ball scales with $r$
- Apply the triangle inequality

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to think about this but I’m not comfortable using the divergence theorem as it was never formally introduced to me. Could you give another hint on how you apply it in such a situation?